# Add values from two raster layer as attribute to a polygon layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, field-calculator, extract

The following data sets are given:

- 1 Polygon layer ("target areas")
- Raster 1 (= digital elevation model)
- Raster 2 (= temperature)

I have the following goals:

For each polygon in "target areas":

- Extract the maximum elevation (including the respective x- and y-coordinates) from Raster 1
- Add max_elev, max_elev_x and max_elev_y as new attributes to the attribute table of "target areas"
- Extract the value at Coordinates max_elev_x/max_elev_y in Raster 2 (= Temperature at highest elevation in each polygon)
- Add temp_max_elev as new attribute to the attribute table of "target areas"

I tried to solve this in QGIS with the field calculator and I am convinced it should work - but I failed so far.

Answer (score 2):

There are in fact three steps you're asking for (last two points are one, in fact). I fear you can't do them at once using filed calculator alone. This is what you can do instead (automatize this workflow creating a model):

1. To get the maximum value of the raster, this can be done using the following expression, where `1` is the band of the raster layer named `raster1`:

   `raster_statistic( 'raster1',1,'max')`
2. To get the coordinates `max_elev_x` and `max_elev_y` of this maximum value is the most difficult part. See the solutions here: [Identify the coordinates of the max values resulting from using the Zonal Statistics tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375686/identify-the-coordinates-of-the-max-values-resulting-from-using-the-zonal-statis) and [Extract highest point in raster and convert to point vector](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255882/extract-highest-point-in-raster-and-convert-to-point-vector)
3. Once you have the coordinates, you can get the raster value of the second raster using filed calculator with this expression, creating an attribute `temp_max_elev`: `raster_value( 'raster2', 1, make_point(max_elev_x,max_elev_y))`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have already tried raster_statistic: with this function I get the maximum value over the entire raster, which is assigned to each individual polygon. So I have the same value in each polygon. However, what I want is the maximum value of the raster within each polygon area - I fail at this point...

Comment: Use Zonal statistics: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-statistics